# Confusion about bokeh 0.11: obtain a user readable session id

Tags: python, bokeh

The documentation for bokeh 0.10 is OK and there are a number of good [examples around](http://brocktane.net/blog/bokeh-server-example/). However, I do not really now how to tell bokeh 0.11 to use an url which is easy to remember. My current try:

import numpy as np
    import time

```
from bokeh.client import push_session
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc, output_server

x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

p = figure()
r2 = p.line(x, y, color="navy", line_width=4)
# open a session to keep our local document in sync with server
session = push_session(curdoc())
session.show() # open the document in a browser
time.sleep(2)
while True:
    x = np.random.rand(10)
    y = np.random.rand(10)
    r2.data_source.data["y"] = y
    r2.data_source.data["x"] = x
    time.sleep(2)
```

From the [Docs](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/client.html):

`push_session(curdoc(),session_id = 'yeah')`

However, the url is still a bit clumsy: `http://localhost:5006/?bokeh-session-id=yeah`
Is there any way to change it to `http://localhost:5006/yeah` ?

EDIT: I should mention, that I am streaming data. The data is gathered by a class which itself is initiated within another class. As a consequence, I cannot easily call `bokeh serve DAQ.py`. Furthermore I do not have a periodic update function. It depends on some process conditions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This method of using the Bokeh server (with `bokeh.client`) is really on suitable for *local, individual* use. There is a useful discussion of different use-case scenarios here

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#use-case-scenarios

If you want to create a "deployable app" that other users can interact with, you absolutely want to create a Bokeh application (which is actually *simpler*). The basic idea is to create a script that you run with the `bokeh serve` command, e.g.

```
bokeh serve myapp.py --show
```

By default this is served at `http://localhost:5006/myapp`. Your code above would be simplified to something like:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc 

x = np.random.rand(10)
y = np.random.rand(10)

p = figure()
r2 = p.line(x, y, color="navy", line_width=4)

# define a callback to update the data
def update():
    x = np.random.rand(10)
    y = np.random.rand(10)

    # important to update all data "at once"
    r2.data_source.data = dict(x=x, y=y)

# run the callback to update the data every 2000 ms
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 2000)
```

Much more information about creating and deploying applications is here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#building-bokeh-applications

All of the command line options for `bokeh serve` are described here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/command/subcommands/serve.html

And several live examples of apps (with links to the source code) are here:

https://demo.bokeh.org

Comment: If I would like to stream data from within a python script (class which does data acquisition), I cannot execute it with `bokeh serve DAQ.py` because it is initiated within another class.  Whould be deployable app be still the best method of choice here ?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't import the class that does the acquisition into the Bokeh app script like any other python module?

Comment: hm, have to think about that. It is called from within kivy.

Comment: There are lots of potential options, it depends alot on your specifics. You might drop by the public mailing list for a more involved discussion.